# Is there an API to turn off IP traffic on iPhone?

Tags: ios, ios4

I'd like to disable any kind of TCP/IP traffic (so, once a user clicks a button, it blocks the phone from accessing internet, until the button is clicked again), from iPhone programmatically without using any private APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is part of the OS already. Settings: Airplane Mode. I don't think the setting is available for Apps since it wold go way beyond what a App should do.